# How to use pattern matching with numbers using node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I have several documents in a collection in MongoDB as shown [in this snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCP1f.jpg) . I'm creating a web app for which this is the back-end data.

Every document has an attribute `name`. The user has an option to search for the `name` in the front-end. Now, suppose the user searches for "Sam", then I'm returning the documents where `name` is either exactly "Sam" or starts with "Sam". I have implemented this using the following code:

```
let name = "^"+req.body.name;
const name_regex = new RegExp(name, 'gi');

try {
  let members = await Member.find({ name: req.body.name=="" ? /^$|/ : name_regex});
  res.send(members);
}
```

i.e., if the user dosen't provide a name, return all documents, else return documents matching the regex.

So , if the user searches for "Sam", the output is all 3 documents since all of them have `name` starting with "Sam", but if the user searches for "Samm", then only one document is returned where the `name` is "Sammy".

Now, I want to implement the same logic on `age` attribute, i.e., if the user searches for age: 2, then I want to return all documents where age is either exactly 2 or starts with the digit 2. But I'm unable to use the above method sine it only works with strings.

Note: I'm using mongoose package and Express framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// regular expression matching anything that starts with two 
const age_regex = /^2/; 

Member.find({
  $expr: {
    $regexMatch: {
      input: {
        $toString: "$age" // Casting the age value to a string
      },
      regex: age_regex
    }
  }
})
```

Some usefule explanatory links: [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/), [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/#exp._S_toString)